# Stripped value from input text that is just numbers doesn't match my simple array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers, match

In this case, I use the example value of "1011AB", which should match, because it is in the array. But somehow, it doesn't match.

```
var postcode = document.getElementById("input_32_16").value;
var postcode = parseInt(String(postcode.replace(/[^0-9]/gmi, '')), 4);
// this will return 1011


var district = [1011, 1012, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1021, 1022, 1023, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028, 1031, 1032, 1033, 1034, 1035, 1036, 1037, 1041, 1042, 1043, 1045, 1046, 1047, 1051, 1052, 1053, 1054, 1055, 1056, 1057, 1058, 1059, 1060, 1061, 1062, 1063, 1064, 1065, 1066, 1067, 1068, 1069, 1071, 1072, 1073, 1074, 1075, 1076, 1077, 1078, 1079, 1081, 1082, 1083, 1086, 1087, 1091, 1092, 1093, 1094, 1095, 1096, 1097, 1098, 1101, 1102, 1103, 1104, 1105, 1106, 1107, 1108, 1109, 1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115];

var campagnemanager = '';
if (district.includes(postcode) == true) {
  var campagnemanager = "emailone";
  // match 1011 with 1011, which should be the case
} else {
  var campagnemanager = "emailtwo";
  // no match, which should not be the case
}
alert(campagnemanager);
```

See also: https://jsfiddle.net/b2xdztv0/2/

Comment: base 4.........   `console.log(parseInt('1011', 4))`

Comment: Remove the 4 from your `parseInt` function, e.g.,: `var postcode = parseInt(String(postcode.replace(/[^0-9]/gmi, '')));`